# Adal UserInfo UniqueId on authenticationresult

Tags: adal

How is the UniqueId field on the authentication result returned from AcquireToken generated. Is this id stable for users who are foreign principlas in other tenants. For example, lets say the user is created in tenant A  and is a foreign principal in tenant B.  When I ask for the token using tenant A, i get a new authentication result with a certain uniqueId. If I then create a new authentication context for tenant B and request a token using the same login in as used for tenant A. I get a token and the uniqueId seems to be the same.

Is this uniqueId stable for both active directory based users and live based users?

I wanted to make sure this behavior was something stable that could be used to make sure I know what tokens are tied to what users reguardless of what tenant they sign into.

Answer (score 3):

ADAL assigns the value of the UniqueId property based on two claims returned by STS. First 'oid' claim and if it does not exist, it uses 'sub' claim. 'oid' is a unique identifier for the user, but unfortunately it is not available all of the times. For example, for pass through users (e.g. MSA). 'sub' claim is generated as a pair of some user identifier and application id, so if the application changes, so does the 'sub' claim. This is why we cannot guarantee that UniqueId is unique across applications and tenants.